# PNG-24 Background Image Blurry In IE8

Tags: internet-explorer-8

I have div and span elements with PNG-24 background images. The background image is pixel sharp, however, they appear blurry in IE8 despite the browser's zoom being set at 100% and text at medium size.

Strangely, when I scroll down and back up, the background images appear sharp again.

This is how it appears:

[image]

After scrolling down and back up, this is how it appears:

[image]

Even in this case, its a bit blurry. This does not occur in IE6, IE7 or IE9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem - PNG-24 images look fine in Firefox but very blurry in IE8. The solution, in IE8 go to **Tools** > **Internet Options** > **Advanced Tab**. In the tree, under the **Multimedia** deselect *Enable Automatic Image Resizing*. This should fix the problem.

Comment: Make sure your zoom is 100%

Answer (score 0):

```
.classid img {
    background: transparent;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#00FFFFFF,endColorstr=#00FFFFFF)"; /* IE8 */   
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#00FFFFFF,endColorstr=#00FFFFFF);   /* IE6 & 7 */      
    zoom: 1;
}
```